# Is it correct to answer "No, yo no viajar en absoluto en tren" to the question "¿Viajas mucho en tren?"?

Tags: gramática, conjugación

My teacher is being very unclear on why my answer for this question is wrong and I just wanted to clarify how I was wrong.

The question is:

> ¿Viajas mucho en tren?

and I answered:

> No, yo no viajar en absoluto en tren.

If someone could explain it a little better that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you are aware that you are not conjugating the verb _viajar_ while answering?

Comment: she said that the problem was the "no" at the beginning of the sentence. she never said anything about the conjugation of the verb, but i do see that now.

Comment: It is funny, here in Spain it sounds fine to say _No, yo no viajo en absoluto en tren_. What dialect of Spanish are you learning? I mean, is she teaching you Spanish from a specific country?

Comment: I've asked her that and she just said "Spanish", so i have no idea.

Comment: Now that I am thinking... maybe _no viajo nunca en tren_ could sound better. That is, [_en absoluto_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0CY07hD) can be seen as something not necessary because it denies very strongly. However, it does not sound incorrect to me. Let's see what other people think about it.

Comment: If you leave out the _yo_ which I suspect most people would then you would leave out the initial _no_ too. Do you think perhaps that is what she was trying to say?

Comment: she said that she wanted me to start the sentence using "yo no viajo...", but never really explained how i was wrong.

Comment: @bajohnson: if the idea is to make a simple negative phrase, then you _must_ drop the initial _No_. The answer then should be _Yo no viajo mucho en tren_. But if you are answering a question, it is required (as a matter of fact, the reply could be just a simple "No."). In either case, if you want to point that you don't travel _often_ then you should include it: _No, no viajo mucho en tren_. Leaving it out or including _en absoluto_ or _nunca_ implies that you _never_ take the train.

Comment: You were correct @bajohnson. No, I don't / No, no viajo... Is perfectly valid and anybody in Spain will understand the sentence. `No, no viajo en absoluto en tren` seems forced `No, no viajo mucho en tren` sounds less forced. Even a simple `muy poco o nada` would be Ok

Comment: Ask her who in Spain answer such question starting with "yo". We elide the subject like she did in the question... What a teacher...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is incorrect because the verb is not correctly conjugated. See, in English, we say

> She/He doesn't travel much
>
> We/They/I don't travel much

It's clear to see the verb 'travel' form doesn't change with the person we're talking about, and is also the same as the infinitive form for it; however, in Spanish, we say

> Ella/El no *viaja* mucho
>
> Yo no *viajo* mucho
>
> Nosotros no *viajamos* mucho
>
> Ellas/Ellos no *viajan* mucho

Take notice on how the verb here does change with the person we're talking about. This is because in Spanish verbs are conjugated differently. For further reference, [here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-t4FaA44i5uE/UTARxEn3rrI/AAAAAAAAAD8/y4vViOXx9Rg/s1600/comparacion+conjucacion+ingl%C3%A9s+espa%C3%B1ol.png) is a chart that might help you. In this chart, the conjugation you're looking for is Present for Yo.

Hope this helps